# TS: Calling an overloaded function with a generic

Tags: typescript

I think this code sums up what I'm trying to do better than I can express:

```
function A(a: string): string;
function A(a: number): number;
function A(a: any) { return a; }

function B<T extends number | string>(arg: T): T {
  return A(arg); // TS error: No overload matches this call.
}
```

So I can call `A(num)`, `A(str)`, but not `A(num | string)`?

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: let’s say you call `B` with an `arg` of type `'one' | 1 | 'two' | 2`, which indeed extends type `number | string`. Why should you expect `A` to be okay with such an argument?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't create generic method for `A`?

Something like this:

```
function A<T>(a: T): T { return a; }

function B<T extends number | string>(arg: T): T {
  return A(arg); // TS error: No overload matches this call.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you think declaring `T extends number | string` means that `T` must be either a `number` or a `string`. In fact, there are subtypes of `number | string` that are not `number` nor `string`.

```
type U = 1 | 'one' | 2 | 'two';

declare const arg: U;

B(arg); // okay, because `U` extends `number | string`

A(arg); // ERROR: type `U`
// is not a subtype of `number` and also
// is not a subtype of `string`
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to implement the signature of `A` without overloads:

```
function A<T extends number | string>(a: T): T { return a; }
```